# Conditional formatting to highlight specific cells but not empty and text cells VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a macro which highlights cells outside a range. The only problem with it, is that it also highlights all empty cells and cells with text. Is there a way for it to ignore these?

[image]

Here is my code

```
Sub Highlight()
'
' Highlight good values

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet


    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    ws.Activate

        With ActiveSheet.Rows("18:79")
            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlNotBetween, _
                Formula1:="=$C18", Formula2:="=$D18"
            .FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
            With .FormatConditions(1).Font
                .Color = -16752384
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 13561798
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
        End With

    Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You currently only have a row limitation to the range you are applying the conditional formatting to. If you want to limit the impacted range you just need to change your `With` to have both a **Row** and a **Column** limitation.

---

**Update This:**

```
With ActiveSheet.Rows("18:79")
```

**To This:**

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("A18:O79")
```

---

### Edit

If each sheet has the **SAME** row range (18:79) but the columns have a **VARYING** range you just need to create a last column variable to create your dynamic range

```
Sub Highlight()

Dim ws As Worksheet, LC As Long

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    LC = ws.Cells(18, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    With ws.Range(ws.Cells(18, 1), ws.Cells(79, LC))
       'Formatting goes here
    End With

Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: The issue is, that the macro runs on multiple sheets where the range changes from sheet to sheet. Sometimes cells have data sometimes they don't. Ideally I want the code to just run on cells with numbers

Comment: Both ranges? I.E. is the ROW always 18:79? Or is it just the column span that changes?

Comment: Row is always 18:79, but columns change sheet to sheet

Comment: updated to be dynamic range. I'm assuming your range starts on Column 1. For syntax for `Cells` is `Cells( Row Index, Column Index)`

Comment: Thanks for that code. It helps me highlight the correct ranges but I still want to know how to not highlight the empty cells. Any Ideas?

Comment: Add a condition where cell value <> ""

Comment: using ```.FormatConditions```?